# Spring MVC log messages not showing

Tags: logging, log4j

In my pom file I have added:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
```

and **properties** file I have

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, file

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Redirect log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
#outputs to Tomcat home
log4j.appender.file.File=/home/preeti/myapp.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

But Still I am not getting any log messages.why?

Comment: *I am not getting any log messages*  `logger.debug("")` logs ?

Comment: yes, like logger.debug("signup " + signup);   this is also not working..

Comment: How is your logger configuration file named?

Comment: @ kryger,  log4j.properties

Answer (score 0):

Add This Line to Your log4j.properties file:

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework=DEBUG
```

Also you can declare your packages log level like above, for example adding:

```
log4j.logger.com.mypackage=WARN
```